# Highcharts JS - Sankey Diagram Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts, axis-labels, sankey-diagram

I am implementing a Sankey Diagram using Highcharts JS and have a problem with specifying the axis. Is it even possible to use xAxis and yAxis on a Sankey diagram?

I tried specifying the axis as following:

```
 yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Test',
            }
        },
 xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Test'
            }
        },
```

but with no success. I tried putting the aforementioned code in `series`, `plotOptions.sankey`, `plotOptions.series` and simply when instantiating the chart but with no result.

Looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `chart.showAxes` option:

```
  chart: {
    showAxes: true
  },
```

Unfortunately in sankey series ticks are not generated for the y axis. It can be done manually like this:

```
  yAxis: [{
    lineWidth: 1,
    tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3]
  }],
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z5p9gba2/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickPositions
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.showAxes

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! However, I don't quite get the meaning of the tickPositioning .. how can I, for instance in your example, place a tick underneath each column?

Comment: I don't think that there's an easy way to do it. For some reason ticks were not generated for the y axis and `y` value of all points (nodes) equals to `1`. I has to be done programmatically and will involve core code analyzing.